# SSP Admin point to new contentdb in SharePoint 2007

Tags: configuration, sharepoint-2007, ssp

I have made in MOSS2007 an contentdb attachment through the UI. Now I have found out that my ssp admin isn't working anymore. Is there a way to attach again the ssp admin to the new contentdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. When crating a SSP infrastructure do not create an Website collection as this will configure the SSP Admin to point to the site collection in the SiteMap Table.

I am not sure but I think that the path for the SSP admin is somehow stored in the Site Collection (This would explain why the SSP admin works again when the original site collection is insertet back again.)